# Firefox Extension - PageMod Script Modifying Window

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, wrapper

I am trying to dynamically create a global function in my Firefox extension:

```
window.performAction= function() { ... };
```

I now know that the window is wrapped by XrayWrapper issue.

```
window -> [object XrayWrapper [object Window]]
```

Thus, it seems that assigning the function does absolutely nothing.  Is there a way to safely modify the window object like this?

Answer (score 0):

from your addon code:

```
gBrowser.contentWindow.addEventListener('customEventListenerMy',doMyFunc,false);
function doMyFunc(){
console.log('doing func');
}
```

`gBrowser.contentWindow` attaches to the currently focused tab document. may need to stick a `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser')` before the gBrowser so `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.contentWindow`

in your window dispatchEvent

```
var event = new Event('customEventListenerMy');
// Dispatch the event.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```